# "Error - ENOENT" while creating a lambda function via cdk

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, node-modules, aws-cdk

I have a node js project which used as a lambda authorizer in AWS. The node project structure will be like below

```
/authorizer
    /lib
       -index.js
-package.json
-node_modules
-package.lock.json
```

I am creating a CDK in typescript to create the lambda function as shown below.
I have given the "entry" value as the path of "index.js".

[image]

But I am getting this below error after that line

[image]

Can you guide me, what exactly missing here? any issue with bundling?

My actual requirement is, that I need to bundle the node_modules folder when I zip and deploy the same via YAML

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: I am not familiar with lambda but `Error: spawnSync docker ENOENT` means `docker` command not found.  You code is trying to run `docker` command but host machine doesn't have it installed.

Comment: @bogdanoff , I haven't used any docker command here

Comment: @Nirmal ya, you didn't directly   but `aws-cdk-lib` does. Share full error stacktrace if you want to know which function is calling that.

Comment: Exception has occurred: Error: spawnSync docker ENOENT

  at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1111:20)

    at Object.spawnSync (node:child_process:814:24)

    at dockerExec (C:\Github\BIB-54\documentTypeApi\infra\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\core\lib\bundling.js:1:4968)

    at Function.fromBuild (C:\Github\BIB-54\documentTypeApi\infra\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\core\lib\bundling.js:1:3553)

Comment: at new Bundling (C:\Github\BIB-54\documentTypeApi\infra\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-lambda-nodejs\lib\bundling.js:1:2057)
    at Function.bundle (C:\Github\BIB-54\documentTypeApi\infra\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-lambda-nodejs\lib\bundling.js:1:2947)
    at new NodejsFunction (C:\Github\BIB54\documentTypeApi\infra\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-lambda-nodejs\lib\function.js:1:1361)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case package `esbuild` is not present in your local env AWS CDK tries to use docker. See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-lambda-nodejs-readme.html#local-bundling

Comment: =====@Lasek, after installing the esbuild getting the below error =====



Exception has occurred: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Github\BIB-54\documentTypeApi\infra\git.COM'
  at Object.statSync (node:fs:1551:3)
    at Object.statSync (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:319:16)
    at Function.sync (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:41:23)
    at Function.sync (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\isexe\index.js:49:17)

Comment: at Function.whichSync [as sync] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:104:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\which.js:5:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)

Comment: make sure code exist at given path, dont use `fromAsset` here, just provide path

Comment: Yes I have given the actual correct path as per the first image on my question